# MySQL select for update, many threads time out

Tags: c++, mysql, database, transactions, timeout

I have a table in MySQL database that holds some "prepared" jobs.

```
CREATE TABLE `ww_jobs_for_update` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `inc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Now I have a C++1y multithreaded application, where each thread goes to the table and selects a job where status=0 (Not completed), does some computation and sets the status=1 upon completion.

The problem is that many threads will acquire a "job row" concurrently so some locking in the database has to take place.

The C++ method that locks/updates/commit is the following

```
connection = "borrow a connection from the pool"
std::unique_ptr<sql::Statement> statement(connection->sql_connection_->createStatement());
connection->sql_connection_->setAutoCommit(false);


//statement->execute("START TRANSACTION");
std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> rs(statement->executeQuery("select id from ww_jobs_for_update where status=0 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE"));


if (rs->next()) {

  db_id = rs->getInt64(1);
  DEBUG << "Unlock Fetched: " << db_id;
}

rs->close();

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "update ww_jobs_for_update set status=1 where id=" << db_id;


statement->execute(ss.str());
//statement->execute("COMMIT;");
connection->sql_connection_->commit();

"release the connection to the pool();"
```

But this approach seems not be efficient. I always get back

> ErrorCode: 1205,SQLState: HY000. Details:

from a lot of threads, especially when there load is increasing.

Why I am getting this back? What is the most efficient way to do this, hard consistency is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for this task in my experience is using redis queues.
Locking tables SELECT ... FOR UPDATE is hanging the database when you have some multi-thread application running etc.

I would advice you to install a redis, and write some scripts to create queues according to the data in tables and rewrite your program to use redis queues for the task.
redis queues will not give the same value for different threads, so you get the uniqueness and there are no locks in the database - so your scripts will work fast.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make your transaction durations shorter? Here's what I mean.

You have status values of 0 for "waiting" and 1 for "complete". Use the status value 2 (or -1, or whatever you choose) to mean "working".

Then when a worker thread grabs a job to do from the table, it will do this (pseudo-SQL).

```
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  SELECT id FROM ww_jobs_for_update WHERE status=0 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
  UPDATE ww_jobs_for_update SET status=2 WHERE id = << db_id
  COMMIT
```

Now, your thread has taken a job and released the transaction lock. When the job is done you simply do this to mark it done, with no transaction needed.

```
UPDATE ww_jobs_for_update SET status=1 WHERE id=" << db_id;
```

There's an even simpler way to do this if you can guarantee each worker thread has a unique identifer  `threadId` .   Put a `thread` column in the table with a default NULL value.  Then to start processing a job.

```
      UPDATE ww_jobs_for_update 
        SET thread = threadId, status = 2
      WHERE status = 0 AND threadId IS NULL
      ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;

      SELECT id FROM ww_jobs_for_update WHERE thread = threadId AND status=2
```

When done

```
      UPDATE ww_jobs_for_update 
        SET thread = NULL, status = 1
      WHERE thread = threadId;
```

Because each thread has a unique threadId, and because individual SQL UPDATE statements are themselves little transactions, you can do this without using any transactions or commits at all.

Both these approaches have the added benefit that you can use a SELECT query to find out which jobs are active. This may allow you to deal with jobs that never completed for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks. I introduced the thread column and executed the following statements: "UPDATE ww_jobs_for_update SET thread =xxx , status = 1 WHERE status = 0 AND thread IS NULL ORDER BY id LIMIT 1"; and 

"SELECT id FROM ww_jobs_for_update WHERE thread=xxxx AND status=1";

Comment: However the error occurs again, 1205 transaction time out. I removed the autoCommit(false) and the ->commit() statement, the db is in autocommit = true mode. The error is still there and is more often when many connection occur at the same time.

Comment: How many concurrent threads are you using in your C++ program? How many concurrent connections to MySQL?  This is counterintuitive, but often you can increase throughput by reducing the number of threads and/or connections.